# clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp' with compile spams-python lib

Tags: python, macos, clang

I'm trying to install the spams-python toolbox for optimize sparse representation problems.

> The download page-> http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/downloads.html
>
> The package link ->
>   http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/hitcounter2.php?file=33816/spams-python-v2.5-svn2014-07-04.tar.gz

I entered its directory, and typed "`pip install .`". The `setup.py` script was executed, and then ended up with error messages.
I also tried to install without using `pip` by typing (got same ends): `python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

The scripy execute:

```
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -Ispams/linalg -Ispams/prox -Ispams/decomp -Ispams/dictLearn -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c spams_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/spams_wrap.o -DNDEBUG -DUSE_BLAS_LIB -fPIC -fopenmp -m32
```

The error message says:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems that my computer does not support `-fopenmp` obviously.

How can I fix it? (mabe by installing some support packages?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you need to upgrade clang, as [it supports OpenMP starting from version 3.8.0](http://openmp.llvm.org). If you're using Apple's development environment, you may have to wait until Apple gets around to upgrading it, though you could first try making sure that Xcode is up to date.

Comment: hey thanks for answering,and dose the apple develop envir refer to the 10.12?

Comment: I'm referring to Xcode. I'm not sure what version you need there, but it sounds as if you're talking about the version of OSX, which is not the same thing.

Comment: To be more precise, I'm still on OSX 10.10.5, so it sounds to me as if you have a more modern OSX. Check to make sure Xcode itself is up to date (App Store should do the trick). If it is, then you probably have to wait.

Another issue is that Apple sometimes releases their own version of clang. I don't remember what it was, but a year or two ago I wanted to do something clang could do, but Xcode's version didn't.

Comment: I am using preview version, and it seems didn't contain some supports or updates, I got to wait for public release now, I think.